# Photoshop save for web

Tags: image, photoshop, file-format

In Photoshop's "Save for web and devices" dialog, how can I choose the file format that ALL the slices will in, without having to go through and select the format for each slice. I have alot of slices and will need to do this more than once.

I'm using Photoshop CS4.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: Slices are still useful with css-based layouts, e.g. rounded corners is currently not supported by standard so you still need to hack css with slices of an image with corners to fix it. That are in different divs also need to be sliced.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you select all the slices and pick the format in the save for web dialogue? You can select multiple slices in the dialogue by shift-clicking them (i.e. hold down shift while you select with your mouse).

Answer (score 2):

Press Ctrl+A

*Edit: according to comments, this doesn't work in CS4 or CS5.*

Comment: Doesn't work in CS 4 or 5. Logged as a bug [here](https://getsatisfaction.com/adobe/topics/is_there_way_to_select_all_slices_in_save_for_web_other_than_by_mouse).

Answer (score 1):

Just click and drag (with the slice tool) inside the Save For Web window. This draws a selection box and will select all slices inside..

"Don't do slices. This is 1990ies with table layout."

That's ridiculous. Images are used all the time for web layouts.